# CSS3 Menu with JQuery Animation not formating and displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have created a jfiddle for this problem at: [JSFiddle showing menu problems](http://jsfiddle.net/jllcpp04/tzn1x7uq/)

I am trying to create a cool menu using jquery and css3 mainly because of familiarity. I would be willing to switch to full CSS3, but I am less sure of how to do that.  I have several problems that I cannot seem to fix. The code is as follows:

javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.hoverIntent = function (f, g) {
        // default configuration options
        var cfg = {
            sensitivity: 7,
            interval: 100,
            timeout: 0
        };
        // override configuration options with user supplied object
        cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? {
            over: f,
            out: g
        } : f);

        // instantiate variables
        // cX, cY = current X and Y position of mouse, updated by mousemove event
        // pX, pY = previous X and Y position of mouse, set by mouseover and polling interval
        var cX, cY, pX, pY;

        // A private function for getting mouse position
        var track = function (ev) {
            cX = ev.pageX;
            cY = ev.pageY;
        };

        // A private function for comparing current and previous mouse position
        var compare = function (ev, ob) {
            ob.hoverIntent_t = clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);
            // compare mouse positions to see if they've crossed the threshold
            if ((Math.abs(pX - cX) + Math.abs(pY - cY)) < cfg.sensitivity) {
                $(ob).unbind("mousemove", track);
                // set hoverIntent state to true (so mouseOut can be called)
                ob.hoverIntent_s = 1;
                return cfg.over.apply(ob, [ev]);
            } else {
                // set previous coordinates for next time
                pX = cX;
                pY = cY;
                // use self-calling timeout, guarantees intervals are spaced out properly (avoids JavaScript timer bugs)
                ob.hoverIntent_t = setTimeout(function () {
                    compare(ev, ob);
                }, cfg.interval);
            }
        };

        // A private function for delaying the mouseOut function
        var delay = function (ev, ob) {
            ob.hoverIntent_t = clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);
            ob.hoverIntent_s = 0;
            return cfg.out.apply(ob, [ev]);
        };

        // A private function for handling mouse 'hovering'
        var handleHover = function (e) {
            // next three lines copied from jQuery.hover, ignore children onMouseOver/onMouseOut
            var p = (e.type == "mouseover" ? e.fromElement : e.toElement) || e.relatedTarget;
            while (p && p != this) {
                try {
                    p = p.parentNode;
                } catch (e) {
                    p = this;
                }
            }
            if (p == this) {
                return false;
            }

            // copy objects to be passed into t (required for event object to be passed in IE)
            var ev = jQuery.extend({}, e);
            var ob = this;

            // cancel hoverIntent timer if it exists
            if (ob.hoverIntent_t) {
                ob.hoverIntent_t = clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);
            }

            // else e.type == "onmouseover"
            if (e.type == "mouseover") {
                // set "previous" X and Y position based on initial entry point
                pX = ev.pageX;
                pY = ev.pageY;
                // update "current" X and Y position based on mousemove
                $(ob).bind("mousemove", track);
                // start polling interval (self-calling timeout) to compare mouse coordinates over time
                if (ob.hoverIntent_s != 1) {
                    ob.hoverIntent_t = setTimeout(function () {
                        compare(ev, ob);
                    }, cfg.interval);
                }

                // else e.type == "onmouseout"
            } else {
                // unbind expensive mousemove event
                $(ob).unbind("mousemove", track);
                // if hoverIntent state is true, then call the mouseOut function after the specified delay
                if (ob.hoverIntent_s == 1) {
                    ob.hoverIntent_t = setTimeout(function () {
                        delay(ev, ob);
                    }, cfg.timeout);
                }
            }
        };

        // bind the function to the two event listeners
        return this.mouseover(handleHover).mouseout(handleHover);
    };

})(jQuery);

$(function () {

    var config = {
        sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
        interval: 200, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
        over: doOpen, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
        timeout: 200, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
        out: doClose // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
    };

    function doOpen() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }

    function doClose() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }

    $("ul.dropdown li").hoverIntent(config);

    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("span:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```

CSS3:

```
.main_nav {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
}
.main_nav ul{
    list-style:outside none none !important;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    width: 80%;
}
/*
    LEVEL ONE
*/

ul.dropdown                         { position: relative; white-space: nowrap;text-wrap: none;}
ul.dropdown li                      { font-weight: bold; float: left;  background: #ffffff; color: #4b2c17; }
ul.dropdown a:hover                 { color: #ffffff; }
ul.dropdown a:active                { color: #ffa500; }
ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #333;
                                      color: #222; }
ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover                { background: rgb(214, 210, 0); color: #ffffff; position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li.hover a              { color: black; }
ul.dropdown li:hover h4             {background: #ffffff;color: #4b2c17;}


/*
    LEVEL TWO
*/
ul.dropdown ul                      { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; padding-left: 0px !important;}
ul.dropdown ul li                   { font-weight: normal; background: #ffffff; color: #4b2c17;
                                      border-bottom: 1px solid #222; float: none; }

                                    /* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a                 { border-right: none; width: 100%; display: inline-block; }

/*
    LEVEL THREE
*/
ul.dropdown ul ul                   { left: 100%; top: 0; }
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul           { visibility: visible; }

/*
    LEVEL Four
*/
ul.dropdown ul ul ul                { left: 100%; top: 0; }
ul.dropdown ul ul li:hover > ul         { visibility: visible; }
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="main_nav">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="/main">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/edituser">User</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li class="subnavhead"><h3>New Users</h3></li>
                <li><a href="/register">Add New User</a></li>
                <li><a href="/validateuser">Validate Users</a></li>
                <li class="subnavhead"><h3>Current Users</h3></li>
                <li><a href="/edituser">Edit User Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="topnav"><a href="#">Head 2</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li><a target="new" href="#">Subhead 1</a></li>
                <li class="subnavhead"><h4><span>Section Group</span></h4>
                    <ul class="thirdnav">
                        <li><a href="#">Subgroup head 1</a>
                            <ul class="thirdnav">
                                <li><a href="#">Subgroup item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Subgroup item 2</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subgroup head 2</a>
                           <ul class="thirdnav">
                               <li><span>Subgroup item head 1</span>
                                    <ul class="thirdnav">
                                        <li><a href="#">third level 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">third level 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                               </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

These codes are supposed to generate a multi-level menu with the ability to track what is highlighted; however, there are several abberrant behaviors within this that I have been currently unable to fix.

The first is the width for the main navigation bar.  I have been unable to get the menu to spread out to fill the menu bar even 80% regardless of the width parameter I have tried to define.

The second is the width of the LI on the drop-down menu components.  As you can see I am able to prevent the line from wrapping, however as shown, the `<li>` does not stretch the width of the longest piece of text.  Along with this, you see the highlight isn't consistent and I do not know why.  I have tried multiple variations and no success.

The last problem is why that stupid >> is showing up on the last html link under sugroup head 2.  The logic doesn't fit that, but it seems to show up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly the issues I think I've resolved 2 and 3. About issue number 1 I simply don't understand what you mean... You want the whole menu to take up the whole page's width? If you could clarify it would be really helpful.

Anyway, for issue number 2 (again, if I understood it correctly) you can make the menu take up the width of the longest item by disabling the wrapping and setting the `width` to `100%`:

```
ul.dropdown ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #4b2c17;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
    width: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

For issue number 3, Prachit had it right. It's the `:has` jQuery selector combined with the `.find` that's giving you trouble, since the `a` tag for "third level 1" is the first descendent `a` tag of a `li` that matches your selector `$("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find(" a:first")`. In this case you should be looking only for direct childs of the `li` that matches your selector, hence your line would turn into:

```
$("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("> a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
```

Anyway, I've updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tzn1x7uq/5/

Hope I could help.

Comment: Closest so far!  What I meant by the first one is that my menu bar wraps inappropriately. I have tried white-space: nowrap;  added but then it screws with my formating of the submenu's

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? jsfiddle.net/tzn1x7uq/16 I wouldn't recommend using this solution if you're going to add options to the main nav bar since the width is set at 30% for all `li` that are direct children of the main nav div and if you add a new voice to the main nav you'll have to update that width to replicate the effect. You can always have a JS do that for you if you want, but I was hoping of finding a pure CSS solution...

Answer (score 1):

The other answers appear to have the good solutions for issues 2 & 3. When using `position:absolute` the children's height and width do not adhere like they normally do. Using `white-space: nowrap` will correct that (although using `width:100%` won't make a difference).

This line:

```
$("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("> a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
```

Works fine, there's other ways to target this besides `:has()` but it works. You can correct the hover issue of "head 2" > "section group" by removing the `background` from the following rule:

```
ul.dropdown li:hover h4 {background: #ffffff;color: #4b2c17;}
```

Lastly is the issue of not being able to set the width. There's a few things that need to happen. For one be sure to set the width on the document:

```
html, body{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Next you need to add the same to all parents (percentage width only works if the parent has a defined width as well). So start with `.main_nav`:

```
.main_nav {
   width: 100%; //add
   background-color:#ffffff;
   text-align:center;
   height:50px;
}
```

On of the biggest reasons you're having issues is because of `.main_nav ul` being set to `display: inline`. `inline` doesn't not respect it's children's width/height therefore calling `width: 100%` will have no effect on it. Change to `inline-block` or just `block` and now add your width:

```
.main_nav ul{
   width: 100%; //add
   list-style:outside none none !important;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block; //add
   padding: 0; //clear the default padding set on ul elements
}
```

Next, Your list items are floating, you'll need to clear those. Typically `overflow:hidden` is a good approach for clearing floats but in this case you have subnavs that will "overflow" your content so you're better off using a clearfix:

```
.main_nav ul:after{
   content: "";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
```

Now you can set the size on your `li`'s:

```
ul.dropdown li { width:33%; font-weight: bold; float: left;  background: #ffffff; color: #4b2c17; }
```

Since your styles are being inherited through shared targeting, you need to overwrite the previous width of `33%` with `width: 100%` for your subnav `li`s:

```
ul.dropdown ul li { font-weight: normal; background: #ffffff; color: #4b2c17; border-bottom: 1px solid #222; float: none; width: 100%; //add }
```

Now your list will take the full width. You have other issues, for one, using `visibility: hidden` is not a great idea. While the element is "hidden" from sight, it still takes up room on the page (as you will see if you scroll right and there is a lot of excess space). There's also the fact that your "head 2" menu has so many subnavs and stretches so far to the right that it's not ideal to be tucked into the corner. You may want to revisit the way it displays. Perhaps have it just drop downwards instead of two the right. Also just a UI/UX tip, having so many levels of dropdowns is not well liked for a user. But that's going to be up to you. Structurally this could use a lot of work, you should take advantage of class names so you don't have children inheriting unwarranted styles but I hope this sets you on the right path:

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzn1x7uq/15/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 you can use it.

<style>
body {
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
/*  background: #E3CAA1;*/
}

ul.dr_menu {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);*/
}
ul.dr_menu li {
  font: bold 12px/18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
/*  background: #fff;*/
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul.dr_menu li:hover {
  background: #0b86c8;
  color: #fff;
}
ul.dr_menu li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul.dr_menu li ul li { 
  background: #0b86c8; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul.dr_menu li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul.dr_menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>


<body>
<ul class="dr_menu">
    <li>
        Add Management
        <ul>
          <li>My Add</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        API Management
        <ul>
          <li>Create API</li>
          <li>Manage API</li>
          <li>Test API</li>
          <li>Document API</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: did not modify the jsfiddle to match the example.  Please do so!

Answer (score 0):

1. The width of main navigation bar does not spread because `.main_nav` have `float: left;`, so if you added width to `li` in percentage it won't spread. You can add `width` to `.main_nav` and then to `li` in percentage, it will spread along the width of `.main_nav`.
2. Set `width` of `li` on drop-down to get desired width drop-down. Not sure what you mean about highlight inconsistent, if you mean about extra white-spaces, it is because heading tags `h3` and `h4` have some default `padding` and `margin`. Set `margin` and `padding` to `0` for `h3` and `h4`.
3. The `>>` shows up because you have used `has` selector in `$("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");`. `has` matches if tag exists anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

Answer (score 0):

is this what youre looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/tzn1x7uq/7/

1a.  Main Menu is 100% width: `width: 100%; /*ADDED LINE*/`

1b.  Menu links take up more space:

```
ul.dropdown li a { 
    display: block; padding: 4px 30px; border-right: 1px solid #333; color: #222; 
}  /*ADDED padding 30px*/
```

2. prevent line wrapping:

   ```
   ul li {white-space: nowrap;} /*ADDED LINE*/
   ```

2b. weird highlighting stuff:

```
h3{ margin: 0px;}
```

also you have a `<h4><span>text here</span></h4>`, i changed it to `<h3>Text here</h3>`

3. random >> caused by `&raquo;`

   ```
   /* COMMENTED OUT: GAVE YOU THE >> things
   $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
   $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("span:first").append(" &raquo;    ");
   */
   ```

hope this helps!

Comment: This is not behaving like the original - you have gave hints but it is close.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the hover effects using CSS only buddy.

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/main">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/edituser">User</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <h3>New Users</h3>
                <a href="/register">Add New User</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/validateuser">Validate Users</a></li>
            <li>
                <h3>Current Users</h3>
                <a href="/edituser">Edit User Information</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li><a href="/edituser">User 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <h3>New Users</h3>
                <a href="/register">Add New User</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <h3>New Users 2</h3>
                        <a href="/register">Add New User</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <h3>New Users 3</h3>
                                <a href="/register">Add New User</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="/validateuser">Validate Users</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <h3>Current Users</h3>
                                <a href="/edituser">Edit User Information</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/validateuser">Validate Users</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Current Users</h3>
                        <a href="/edituser">Edit User Information</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/validateuser">Validate Users</a></li>
            <li>
                <h3>Current Users</h3>
                <a href="/edituser">Edit User Information</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/edituser">User 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <h3>New Users</h3>
                <a href="/register">Add New User</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/validateuser">Validate Users</a></li>
            <li>
                <h3>Current Users</h3>
                <a href="/edituser">Edit User Information</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For CSS

```
#navigation:before,
#navigation:after { clear: both; content: ' '; display: block; }
#navigation ul { padding: 0; }
#navigation li { float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; } 
#navigation li a { display: block; padding: 5px 15px; text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap; }
#navigation li a:hover { background-color: #222; color: #fff; }
#navigation li ul,
#navigation li:hover ul ul,
#navigation li li:hover ul ul { display: none; position: absolute; }
#navigation li:hover ul,
#navigation li li:hover ul,
#navigation li li li:hover ul { display: block; }
#navigation li li { float: none; } 
#navigation ul ul ul { left: 100%; top: 0;}
h3 { margin: 0; }
```

[js fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/gc0w1k1s/)